# Remove Updated Software Notification on 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, updates, notification

Pop - Up "Updated Software is available for this computer. Do you want to install now"[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNXVn.png)

1. I have set the updater to Never
2. I have disabled the notification
3. I have tried the "pkill update-notifier"
4. sudo systemctl disable apt-update-daily.service and timer disabled to "0"

Can some one help to remove the notification completely?

Answer (score 3):

**Warning: the below answer disables update popups, this may end with lower security level for your system. Continue only if you are sure.**

To disable update-notifier popup on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS use the following commands:

```
# disable cron jobs for Update Notifier
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common

# disable graphical Update Notifier application
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop ~/.config/autostart/

grep -q "^X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled" ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop && sed -i "s/X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=true/X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=false/" ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop || echo "X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=false" >> ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
```

and then reboot.

To disable update-notifier popup on Ubuntu 21.04 use the following commands:

```
# disable cron jobs for Update Notifier
sudo systemctl disable update-notifier-download.timer
sudo systemctl disable update-notifier-motd.timer

# disable graphical Update Notifier application
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop ~/.config/autostart/

grep -q "^X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled" ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop && sed -i "s/X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=true/X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=false/" ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop || echo "X-$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP-Autostart-enabled=false" >> ~/.config/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
```

and then reboot.

Comment: The question is indeed for 20.04, but maybe it is good to also explicitly repeat that in your answer. In 21.04 it is probably a systemd service instead of a cron job.

Comment: OP wants 20.04, but I have added 21.04 as useful addition. Thanks!

Comment: I know OP specifies 20.04, but in the future, other users will bump on this. Anyway, you took it one step further and now even made the answer future proof!